# jQuery selector, css path replace :eq

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with my JavaScript script.

I need to export a CSS style that I have set with a tool to a browser readable CSS file.
A JavaScript function gets the path of the element that I change and returns something like this:

```
html>body>div:eq(2)>div>div:eq(1)>article>div>div>p:eq(1){text-decoration:underline;}
```

The path works great with as a jQuery selector, but not valid in CSS file.

I've tried to replace the `:eq` element by `:nth-child` but despite it's a valid CSS file, the style won't apply.

What am I doing wrong?
How can i convert my :eq to something that css understand.

Comment: to change all ocurrence of the string use : var regExp = new RegExp(":eq", "g");
css = css.replace(regExp,':nth-child');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after a while, i found an answer, what i am trying to do can't be done in css.

The :eq jQuery selector can't be translate in pure css.

The jQuery element is 0 based when the nth-child start to count at 1.

As i understand if we got an HTML like this

```
<div>
    <div id="ele1" class="foo"></div>
    <div id="ele2" class="foo"></div>
    <div id="ele3" class="foo"></div>
</div>
```

The selector .foo:eq(0) return #ele1, while we need .foo:nth-child(1) to get the same element.
and if we transform the dom to

```
<div>
    <div id="ele0"></div>
    <div id="ele1" class="foo"></div>
    <div id="ele2" class="foo"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

The same selector with eq(0) will return #ele1 while nth-child(1) will return nothing because the first child of the container not match .foo.

In fact, if we try to get nth-child(2), in the first case we got #ele2, but in the second container will return #ele1.

That because the nth-child select the n element from the parent that match to the selector.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass second argument flag in **[RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)** for global search:

> new RegExp(pattern[, flags])

Use:

```
var regExp = new RegExp('(:eq)','g');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/krkjrjkr/)**

Comment: Thanks, i have tried to write it in the first argument, and it did not does the jobs, but as second it's work fine.

Comment: @Leze: glad it helps :)